# Changing value of XML attribute removes other attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have created a simple XSLT based on various questions around StackOverflow on modifying XML attribute value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@Name[.='Source']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">MROClass</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I apply it to the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="dirD33FABDFBCD72FAC87416BC87B4323D1" Name="Source" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The problem is the Id attribute is modified, but the Name attribute is removed. How do I modify single attribute without removing others? I have tried using copy and other methods, but the results are always the same.

Sample Output:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
            <Directory Id="MROClass" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` attribute is removed because that's what you're matching.

If you want to update the `Id` attribute, but based on the `Name` attribute, try changing:

```
match="@Name[.='Source']"
```

to:

```
match="*[@Name='Source']/@Id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy over the original value in current context of matched template by adding the following. Right now you are re-writing the *Name* attribute entirely with just a new *Id* attribute.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

Fuller version:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@Name[.='Source']">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">MROClass</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```